# How to listen to JSON file update using java

Tags: java, json, node.js, push-notification

I create java program that load JSON file from [url](http://frozen-brook-16337.herokuapp.com/history.json) , I push json object to this [url](http://frozen-brook-16337.herokuapp.com/history.json) every 20 seconds I want the program to give notification when the JSON file updated here is my java code

```
package com.company;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Main {
    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonText);
        return jsonArray;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONArray json = readJsonFromUrl("http://frozen-brook-16337.herokuapp.com/history.json");
    for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
        JSONObject jo=json.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(jo.get("data"));
     }

 }

}
```

How to make java program listen to JSON file update ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have update the question

Comment: I don't see that your code has change any file? Your code just read data and print it out

Comment: yes the JSON file is updated using nodejs not the java, so the java program only need to give notification when JSON file updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a scheduler that executes your bit of code after every 20 seconds. There are multiple ways to achieve this.

A good robust way would be to use something like [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
Or for a quick solution you can also create a Thread and have its run() method execute the code in a loop.

```
public class MyPush implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
         long twentySeconds = 20*1000L;
        while(true) {
          //execute your code
           Thread.sleep(twentySeconds);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new MyPush())).start();
    }

}
```